# How to calculate no. of days in an year in particular time period in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datediff

Below is a sample of medical insurance details of members in an organization. And we have to find out no. of days each member is insured in particular year.
**date format for below data is mm-dd-yyyy**

```
SELECT \* FROM MED_INSURANCE

INSERT INTO MED_INSURANCE VALUES

('M1','1-1-2017','11-20-2017')
,('M1','12-31-2017','02-01-2018')
,('M1','02-15-2018','04-30-2018')
,('M1','06-10-2018','12-31-2018')
,('M2','1-1-2017 ','11-20-2017')
,('M2','12-31-2017','02-01-2018')
,('M3','02-15-2018','04-30-2018')
,('M3','06-10-2018','12-31-2018')
,('M4','1-1-2017','11-20-2017')
,('M4','12-31-2017','02-01-2018')
,('M5','02-15-2018','04-30-2018')
,('M5','06-10-2018','12-31-2018')
,('M6','01-01-2017','12-31-2019')
,('M7','12-31-2017','12-30-2018')
,('M8','1-1-2020','12-31-2020')
,('M9','06-30-2018','01-31-2020')
```

Output should be something like

```
memberid        no_of_days_insured_in_2018
m1                      309
.
.
.
.
m7                      363
```

Comment: Is it *just* the number of days in 2018 you want?

Comment: Also, please don't use ambiguous date formats; there aren't 31 months in the year. `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnn)` are completely unambiguous and so can't cause conversion errors.

Comment: we have to find no. of days they are insured in given year. 2018 is just for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a specific year, as you imply, then you can `DATEDIFF` with some `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT YD.ID,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,
                    CASE WHEN YD.StartDate < '20180101' THEN '20180101'
                         WHEN YD.StartDate >= '20190101' THEN NULL
                         ELSE YD.StartDate
                    END,
                    CASE WHEN YD.EndDate < '20180101' THEN NULL
                         WHEN YD.EndDate >= '20190101' THEN '20181231'
                         ELSE YD.EndDate
                    END) + 1) AS DaysIn2018
FROM (VALUES ('M1', '1-1-2017', '11-20-2017'),
             ('M1', '12-31-2017', '02-01-2018'),
             ('M1', '02-15-2018', '04-30-2018'),
             ('M1', '06-10-2018', '12-31-2018'),
             ('M2', '1-1-2017 ', '11-20-2017'),
             ('M2', '12-31-2017', '02-01-2018'),
             ('M3', '02-15-2018', '04-30-2018'),
             ('M3', '06-10-2018', '12-31-2018'),
             ('M4', '1-1-2017', '11-20-2017'),
             ('M4', '12-31-2017', '02-01-2018'),
             ('M5', '02-15-2018', '04-30-2018'),
             ('M5', '06-10-2018', '12-31-2018'),
             ('M6', '01-01-2017', '12-31-2019'),
             ('M7', '12-31-2017', '12-30-2018'),
             ('M8', '1-1-2020', '12-31-2020'),
             ('M9', '06-30-2018', '01-31-2020')) V (ID, StartDate, EndDate)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(V.ID, CONVERT(date,StartDate,101), CONVERT(date,V.EndDate,101)))YD(ID, StartDate, EndDate)
GROUP BY YD.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select memberid, sum(no_of_days_insured) as no_of_days_insured_in_2018
from(
select MemberID
      ,DATEDIFF(DD,CAST(Insurance_Start_Date AS DATE),Insurance_End_Date) as no_of_days_insured
from
(select memberid,
       case when (year([Insurance End Date])=2018 and year([Insurance Start Date])!=2018) then '2018-01-01'
            when (year([Insurance Start Date]) < 2018 and year([Insurance End Date])>2018) then '2018-01-01'
            else [Insurance Start Date] end as Insurance_Start_Date
       ,case when (year([Insurance End Date])!=2018 and year([Insurance Start Date])=2018) then '2018-12-31'
             when (year([Insurance End Date])>2018 and year([Insurance Start Date])<2018) then '2018-12-31'
       else [Insurance End Date] end AS Insurance_End_Date
from [Medical Insurance]
)A
where year(Insurance_End_Date)=2018
)B
group by MemberID
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.